# Viewbag New Selectlist Placeholder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

I have a simple select list being generated in my action method (code below)

```
Viewbag.Select = new SelectList(db.esp_admin_form_demographics.Where(x => x.category == (int) SelectHelper.ClientSelectOptions.Demographics.BirthCountry || x.category == 999), "id", "value", "");
```

How is it possible to add a placeholder value in there as the default value?

Comment: What do you mean a _placeholder_? Are you wanting to have the first option as (say) _Please select_?

Comment: @StephenMuecke "Placeholder" means a value set as initial value that will shown when `SelectList` bound to a DDL or DDLF. Similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073464/asp-net-mvc-how-to-add-placeholder-for-html-dropdownlist) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468499/cannot-find-a-way-to-add-a-placeholder-for-an-mvc-5-dropdownlistfor/28469469).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, Its only the initial (default) value if the property OP is binding to does not match a value of one of the options (which is why I was asking)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create DropDownListFor from SelectList with default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215558/create-dropdownlistfor-from-selectlist-with-default-value)

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI, I do not think that is what OP is asking, but in anycase that answer is completely wrong as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719293/mvc5-how-to-set-selectedvalue-in-dropdownlistfor-html-helper/41731685#41731685) (no idea how it was accepted)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the solution to set placeholder as the default value in your SelectList/DropDownList :**

In the Controller Method:

```
var espAdminList =  db.esp_admin_form_demographics.Where(x => x.category == (int) SelectHelper.ClientSelectOptions.Demographics.BirthCountry || x.category == 999)

Viewbag.EspAdminSelectList = new SelectList(espAdminList, "id", "value");
```

Then in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("EspAdminId",ViewBag.EspAdminSelectList as SelectList, "Select Esp. Admin", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Your code does not work - You have not cast `ViewBag.EspAdminSelectList`

Comment: Sorry! forgot that! Thanks for noticing that! I have updated the answer